# Other way to scan values in a .txt file apart using arrays?

Tags: c

Im new to C and am currently writing a code where I have to scan a list of random integers from a .txt file, but without the usage of arrays. This is the code I used for writing the program with the help of an array to read 5 random integers from the .txt file.

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
 {
    FILE *fp;
    int a[5];
    int i = 0;
    int x;

    fp = fopen("testdata4", "r");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &a[i]);
    printf("%d\n", a[i]);
}
fclose(fp);

return 0;
}
```

How should I write the code so that it reads a .txt file without an array and reads the integers from the file to the output?

Answer (score 2):

For your particular case you do not need array as you are just printing these values after read. You can use a variable to read integers from the file

```
FILE *fp;
int a;
int x;
fp = fopen("testdata4", "r");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &a);
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

Comment: If I have a huge list of integers in a file and I have to read them, declaring variable for each one of them will be too long. So for such situations, how should I approach the problem?

Comment: You need to declare only one variable.